# How can I add a value that is incremented every 2nd time to each object of an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm stuck with some math problem. I have this simple array:

```
var x = [
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 1,
    },
    {
        'index':1,
        "place": 4,
    },
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 9,
    },
    {
        'index':1,
        "place": 9,
    },
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 9,
    },
];
```

How can I loop through this array and add an element (called `row` in this case) to each object within the array? It should look like this in the end:

```
var x = [
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 1,
        "row":"0",
    },
    {
        'index':1,
        "place": 4,
        "row":"0",
    },
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 9,
        "row":"1",
    },
    {
        'index':1,
        "place": 9,
        "row":"1",
    },
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 9,
        "row":"2",
    },
    {
        'index':0,
        "place": 9,
        "row":"2",
    },
];
```

Thanks for any advice. I need this to create a dynamic grid layout in NativeScript.

Comment: How about adjusting the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52791323/how-to-add-index-to-nested-array-with-value-0-or-1-depending-on-array-length) which shows how to add the `index` property

Comment: What is the business logic behind the values of row? And will it vary for other fields that need to be added? Can you please provide some insights?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just divide the index by two:

```
x.forEach((e, i) => e.row = ~~(i / 2));
```

**PS:** The `~~` is a very ugly shortform of `Math.floor` ...

Comment: @jenny is it really benefitial to **stress** some irrelevant abbreviations? :)

Comment: Sorry, I thought that it makes the post more readable. :-( And it's not the only thing I changed.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :)

```
var x = [
        {
            'index':0,
            "place": 1,
        },
        {
            'index':1,
            "place": 4,
        },
        {
            'index':0,
            "place": 9,
        },
        {
            'index':1,
            "place": 9,
        },
        {
            'index':0,
            "place": 9,
        },
         {
            'index':0,
            "place": 1,
        },
        {
            'index':1,
            "place": 4,
        },
        {
            'index':0,
            "place": 9,
        },
        {
            'index':1,
            "place": 9,
        },
        {
            'index':0,
            "place": 9,
        },
    ];

    var j = -1
    x.forEach(function(e, i) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
     j++
    }
      e['row'] = j
    })

    console.log(x)
```

Comment: Thanks guys. @Jonas Wilms - easy and brillant !